# A better way to create the body of a NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm new to objective-c and am wondering if there is a better way that the following to create the HTTP POST body that the method I have below.

```
- (NSData*) generateBody: (NSDictionary*) requestParams {
NSMutableData *body = [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:1024] autorelease]; 

BOOL firstParam = YES;

for (NSString* key in requestParams) {
    NSString *value = [requestParams valueForKey:key];

    if ( firstParam ) {
        firstParam = NO;
    } else {
        [body appendData:[@"&" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"=" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

return body;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Have a look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) , specifically, the ASIFormDataRequest class (just search for it in that link)

It's like a better version of NSURLConnection :) It also seems to be becoming the industry standard way to do web requests and an essential part of every iOS developers library of tools :)

Answer (score 0):

If it accepts JSON formatted data try looking at NSJSONSerialization in the Apple docs. Works great.